# Does the redips drag drop library support mobile?

Tags: javascript, dojo, hybrid-mobile-app, redips.drag

I'm developing a hybrid application in Worklight.
I would like to have drag and drop features like the redips drag and drop library.

http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/

My question is:
Will these features work with the mobile devices?

Comment: Have you tired testing it yourself?

Comment: I tried it on a Samsung galaxy tablet. On the chrome browser it works fine, but on the standard browser it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, nexus 4 and samsung note...
Then I made a new WORKLIGHT project and tested it again, it works even better!

Hope you will all be testing this.

Comment: What browser did you use? @Fred

Comment: Chrome on the tab, and the native browsers on the others. The javascript was not working so fine om the native browser of the SG-tab3

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with iscroll, redisp will fail.